# JQuery Autocomplete : can't apply style on the focused item

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a simple input like that

`<input id="name-srch" type="text" data-type="string">`

And my js (simplified)

```
$('#name-srch').autocomplete({
  source: function (request, response) {
      $.ajax({
          url: ...,
          data: ...,
          success: function (data) {
              // note that 'data' is the list of elements to display
              response(data)
          }
      });
  },
  select: function (event, ui) {
      // do some stuff
      return false
  },
  focus: function (event, ui) {
      console.log(ui.item.Name) // just to see if the focus event is triggered, and it is
      return false
  }
})
.autocomplete("instance")._renderItem = function (ul, item) {
    return $("<li>")
        .append("<a>" + item.Name + "</a>")
        .appendTo(ul);
};
```

JQuery Autocomplete fill the `<ul>` with the `<li>s` as it should and triggers a focus event on mouseover or down/up arrow key as it should.

The problem is that I want to apply a particular style to the focused item, so in my CSS I have something like that

```
.ui-state-focus {
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

There is my problem, the focused item never takes the `ui-state-focus` class and therefore it never takes the defined style.

What am I doing wrong :( ?

**EDIT :** I already tried to add in my CSS something like

```
.ui-menu-item:hover {
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Indeed it does the trick for the hover, but not for the focus via down/up arrow key. Moreover, I don't really like it, I would prefer to make it work the way it's meant to if I can...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I managed to make it work.

For some reason JQuery Autocomplete doesn't apply the `ui-state-focus` on the focused `<li>` but does apply the `ui-state-active` class on the `<a>` **inside** the focused `<li>`. Therefore I can apply the wanted style via

```
.ui-state-active {
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

I still have no idea why it applies a class only on the `<a>` inside and not on the `<li>` as describe on all the documentations but hey, it works...

Answer (score 4):

try this selector:

```
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item:hover, .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus {
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

There is a JSFIDDLE from another question that I've answered. Just check the last line in the CSS definition:

https://jsfiddle.net/g4bvs0we/5/

**Update**: I've updated the source code and jsfiddle link. I guess there were issue with CSS rule priority and putting more specific rule should help.

Can you please let me know if this works?

Comment: Yeah I thought about that and tried this already (should have mention that maybe). Indeed it works for the hover but the not for the focus via down/up arrow key :/ Isn't there any way to make it work the way it's meant to ?

Comment: Same problem as previously, does the trick on the hover (due to the `.ui-menu-item:hover` for sure) but the style is not applied in case of focus via down/up key. I think the problem might not be in my CSS. Somehow it seems like JQuery Autocomplete is not doing his job applying the right classes (in my case `ui-state-focus`), if I can manage to make it work correctly I'm saved. My version of JQuery UI is the 1.12.0 by the way

Comment: I don't know why your fiddle works but not mine. I copied the code from jQuery's example. https://jsfiddle.net/18b15bw1

Comment: Very good , thanks a lot , I've been looking for a decent answer for 2 hours but nothing , however your line did it for me : `.ui-menu .ui-menu-item:hover, .ui-state-hover, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover, .ui-state-focus, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus {
            background-color: #2b2e8f;
            font-weight: bold;
        }`

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a different way to skin this is to add a class to the li in the javascript then add in something like this

```
.li-hover:hover {
    background-color: red;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Might do the trick, as a guess I think because you are setting a different render jquery autocomplete isn't doing the hover for you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by using:

```
.ui-autocomplete {
    .ui-state-focus {
        border: 0px !important;
        background: #yourcolour !important;
        color: #yourcolour !important;
    }
}
```